# Integration in many variables.

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that 
$$
\int_a^b\,\left(\int_a^y\,f\,(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy\,=\,\int_a^b\,\left(\int_x^b\,f\,(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx
$$

Comment: i don't think this is generally true, are there any restrictions on $f$?

Comment: I only need for $f:\,[a,b]\,\times\,[a,b]\,\longrightarrow\,\R$ to be integrable.

Comment: that's a restriction on $f$, you likely want to update your question with that assumption in place. Please look at Fubini's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) in the section for integrable functions

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\chi_{[a,y]}(x) = [a \leq x \leq y]$.($\chi$ is the indicator function and $[\cdot]$ is the Iverson bracket) Then
$$\begin{align*} \int_a^b \int_a^y f(x,y)dx\,dy &= \int_a^b \int_a^b \chi_{[a,y]}(x) f(x,y)dx\,dy \\
&= \int_{[a,b]^2} \chi_{[a,y]}(x) f(x,y)dx \times y \\
&= \int_a^b \int_a^b [a \leq x \leq y] f(x,y)dy\,dx \\
&= \int_a^b \int_x^b f(x,y)dy\,dx
\end{align*}$$

I assume that $f$ satisfy the condition for Fubini-Tonelli Theorem.