# Using Fubini How to prove the following equality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $1<x<y<z$. Using Fubuni how to prove that 
$$\int_{x}^{\infty} f(y) \int_{y}^{\infty} g(y,z) \, dz \, dy = \int_{x}^{\infty} h(z) \int_{x}^{z} k(y,z) \, dy \, dz \,\, ??$$
where  $f,g,h,k$ are  real functions and are given.

Forget the functions $f,g,h,k$, my broblem is the passage from $\int_{x}^{\infty}  \int_{y}^{\infty} \, dz \, dy $ to $ \int_{x}^{\infty} \int_{x}^{z}  \, dy \, dz \,\,$ ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't make any sense in this way. What is $1 < x < y < z$ meant to be? Also, you use $f$ as a function of one parameter as well as a function of two parameters

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense either… take $f = g = 0$ and $h = k = 1$ then it's obviously false… and if they are GIVEN (as added in the third edit) one need to know them to check the equation

Comment: For arbitrarry functions $f,g,h,k$? This makes even less sense.

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. We can't just "forget" the functions, because the equation is completely wrong for most functions.

Comment: [This is probably the answer you want](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1685010/8157)

Comment: Yes. thank you @ Giuseppe Negro